# CSS hover isn't working ,the idea is for multi-level dropdown

Tags: html, css

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.company
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#navigation
{
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* padding: 10px; */
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#logo
{
    height: 70%;
    margin: 8px 0px 2px 15px ;
}
.item
{
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin:15px;
    /* border-right: 1px solid white; */

}
.item a
{
    transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
    /* transition-delay: 0.2s; */

}
a:hover
{
    font-size:1.2em
}
a:after
{
    transition: 0.2s;
    font-size:1em
}
.nav-options
{
    margin-top:20px ;
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  
  /* Links inside the navbar */
  .navbar a {
    float: left;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 14px 16px; */
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /* The dropdown container */
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
   .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: inherit; 
    background-color: inherit; 
    margin: 0;
  }
  

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* min-width: 160px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 1em;
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  /* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .d2
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    /* transition: 0.3s; */
    display: none;
  }

  .cps:hover > ul
  {
    display: block;
  }

.bi-caret-right-fill
{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.bi-caret-right-fill:hover
{
    transition: ease 0.25s;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.bi-caret-right-fill:after
{
    transition: ease 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="for stackOverflow.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="navigation">
        <div><img id="logo" alt="ignore"/></div>
        <div>
        <ul class="nav-options">
            <li class="item"><span class="link 3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropbtn">Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a class="cps" href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" 
                    class="bi bi-thermometer-sun" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M5 12.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-2-1.415V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v8.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5z"/>
                        <path
                         d="M1 2.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0v7.55a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-5 0V2.5zM3.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2 2.5v7.987l-.167.15a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 3.333 0L5 10.486V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 1zm5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm4.243 1.757a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-.707.708a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l.708-.707a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zM8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5 3 3 0 1 1 0 6 .5.5 0 0 1 0-1 2 2 0 0 0 0-4 .5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM12.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.172 2.828a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.707.708a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.707l-.708-.707a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708zM8.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="cps-text">Climate Policy & Sustainability</span>
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" 
                      fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path 
                          d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <ul class="d2" style="list-style-type: none;">
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown2">Energy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown2">Thermal Consumption</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                    
                        
                  <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-building-gear" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M2 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h10a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1H3v14h3v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H8v4H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V1Z"/>
                        <path d="M4.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm-6 3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm-6 3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm4.386 1.46c.18-.613 1.048-.613 1.229 0l.043.148a.64.64 0 0 0 .921.382l.136-.074c.561-.306 1.175.308.87.869l-.075.136a.64.64 0 0 0 .382.92l.149.045c.612.18.612 1.048 0 1.229l-.15.043a.64.64 0 0 0-.38.921l.074.136c.305.561-.309 1.175-.87.87l-.136-.075a.64.64 0 0 0-.92.382l-.045.149c-.18.612-1.048.612-1.229 0l-.043-.15a.64.64 0 0 0-.921-.38l-.136.074c-.561.305-1.175-.309-.87-.87l.075-.136a.64.64 0 0 0-.382-.92l-.148-.045c-.613-.18-.613-1.048 0-1.229l.148-.043a.64.64 0 0 0 .382-.921l-.074-.136c-.306-.561.308-1.175.869-.87l.136.075a.64.64 0 0 0 .92-.382l.045-.148ZM14 12.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 0Z"/>
                      </svg>
                    Infrastructure Design & Life Safety
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                      </svg>
                </a>
                  <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-code-slash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M10.478 1.647a.5.5 0 1 0-.956-.294l-4 13a.5.5 0 0 0 .956.294l4-13zM4.854 4.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L1.707 8l3.147 3.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zm6.292 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708L14.293 8l-3.147 3.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
                      </svg>
                    Software & AI
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                      </svg>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div></span>
        </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Articles & Resources</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
            <script src=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js” integrity=”sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl” crossorigin=”anonymous”></script>    
    </body>
 </html>
```

CSS hover isn't working ,the idea is for multi-level dropdown ,hover on Services in navbar and then hover on climate policy option. HTML,CSS shared. There is also 2 empty option boxes that i can't ride of in this second dropdown .Also display:none is working to hide this second dropdown but visibility:hidden isn't working.

I tried display:none which works then on hovering address i expected it to show bcoz i set it to display:block.Also visibility:hidden isnt working as opposed to display:none.

There are also 2 empty option boxes at the top of second dropdown which i cant seem to get rid off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `.cps:hover > ul` with `.cps:hover + ul`. The unordered list is not a child of `.cps` but a sibling.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.company {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navigation {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#logo {
  height: 70%;
  margin: 8px 0px 2px 15px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 15px;
  /* border-right: 1px solid white; */
}

.item a {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  /* transition-delay: 0.2s; */
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 1.2em
}

a:after {
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 1em
}

.nav-options {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Navbar container */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  /* padding: 14px 16px; */
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The dropdown container */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /* min-width: 160px; */
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 1em;
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.d2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /* transition: 0.3s; */
  display: none;
}

.cps:hover+ul {
  display: block;
}

.bi-caret-right-fill {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.bi-caret-right-fill:hover {
  transition: ease 0.25s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bi-caret-right-fill:after {
  transition: ease 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <div><img id="logo" alt="ignore" /></div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav-options">
      <li class="item"><span class="link 3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropbtn">Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a class="cps" href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" 
                    class="bi bi-thermometer-sun" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M5 12.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1-2-1.415V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v8.585A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5z"/>
                        <path
                         d="M1 2.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0v7.55a3.5 3.5 0 1 1-5 0V2.5zM3.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2 2.5v7.987l-.167.15a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 3.333 0L5 10.486V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 1zm5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm4.243 1.757a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-.707.708a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l.708-.707a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zM8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5 3 3 0 1 1 0 6 .5.5 0 0 1 0-1 2 2 0 0 0 0-4 .5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM12.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.172 2.828a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.707.708a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.707l-.708-.707a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708zM8.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="cps-text">Climate Policy & Sustainability</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path 
                          d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                        </svg>
        <ul class="d2" style="list-style-type: none;">
          <li><a href="#" class="dropdown2">Energy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="dropdown2">Thermal Consumption</a></li>
        </ul>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-building-gear" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M2 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h10a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1H3v14h3v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H8v4H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V1Z"/>
                        <path d="M4.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm-6 3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm-6 3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm3 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1Zm4.386 1.46c.18-.613 1.048-.613 1.229 0l.043.148a.64.64 0 0 0 .921.382l.136-.074c.561-.306 1.175.308.87.869l-.075.136a.64.64 0 0 0 .382.92l.149.045c.612.18.612 1.048 0 1.229l-.15.043a.64.64 0 0 0-.38.921l.074.136c.305.561-.309 1.175-.87.87l-.136-.075a.64.64 0 0 0-.92.382l-.045.149c-.18.612-1.048.612-1.229 0l-.043-.15a.64.64 0 0 0-.921-.38l-.136.074c-.561.305-1.175-.309-.87-.87l.075-.136a.64.64 0 0 0-.382-.92l-.148-.045c-.613-.18-.613-1.048 0-1.229l.148-.043a.64.64 0 0 0 .382-.921l-.074-.136c-.306-.561.308-1.175.869-.87l.136.075a.64.64 0 0 0 .92-.382l.045-.148ZM14 12.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 0Z"/>
                      </svg> Infrastructure Design & Life Safety
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                      </svg>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-code-slash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M10.478 1.647a.5.5 0 1 0-.956-.294l-4 13a.5.5 0 0 0 .956.294l4-13zM4.854 4.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L1.707 8l3.147 3.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zm6.292 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708L14.293 8l-3.147 3.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3.5-3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0z"/>
                      </svg> Software & AI
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="m12.14 8.753-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
                      </svg>
        </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </span>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Utilities</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Articles & Resources</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src=”https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js” integrity=”sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl” crossorigin=”anonymous”></script>
```

Comment: i found a different way....i changed the HTML and put diff. code in css.  
 dropdown-content:hover .d2 {
    display: block;
  }                Btw ur code also works, and i got to learn a new way so thanx.